# EF multiple dbcontext throws various exceptions when starting with high concurrency request

Tags: entity-framework

i reference  an  ApiLog project (C# library, write logs to database in IActionFilter)  into a business project(web api), both of them define their own  DbContext ， named  LogContext and BusinessContext:

```
public class LogContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ApiLogBase> LogBases { get; set; }
}

 public class BusinessContext:
{
 public DbSet<lsapi.Models.Company> Companys { get; set; }
 public DbSet<lsapi.Models.CompanyFee> CompanyFees { get; set; }
}
```

they are cached in CallContext,and invoked in repository

```
public static BusinessContext GetCurrDBContext()
    {
         BusinessContext ctx= (BusinessContext)CallContext.GetData("cachekey");
        if (ctx == null)
        {
            ctx = new BusinessContext();
            CallContext.SetData("cachekey", ctx);
        }
        return ctx;
    }
```

the LogContext used in Repository,

```
     public LogRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        var logContextData = CallContext.GetData(logContextKey);
        if (logContextData == null)
        {
            LogContext logContext = new LogContext(connectionString);
            logContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
            CallContext.SetData(logContextKey, logContext);
            db = logContext;
        }
        else
        {
            db = (LogContext)logContextData;
        }
    }
```

,and the repository is injected into Application , and application is injected  into a customer IActionFilter:

```
 public class APILogActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    ILogApplication logapp;

    public APILogActionFilter(ILogApplication logapp)
    {
        this.logapp= logapp;

    }
```

all of above(repository,application ,iactionfilter) is registered into caslt.windsor:

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    string logConnectionStringName;
    public Installer(string logConnectionStringName )
    {
        this.logConnectionStringName = logConnectionStringName;
    }
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {

        //db
        container.Register(Component.For< ILogRepository>().ImplementedBy<LogRepository>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", logConnectionStringName))
            );
        //application
        container.Register(Component.For< ILogApplication>().ImplementedBy<LogApplication>());
        //actionfilterattrite
        container.Register(Component.For<IActionFilter>().ImplementedBy<APILogActionFilter>());

    }
}
```

they are bootstraped in the Global.ascx.cs  of Business project。

```
using ApiLog；
public class bootstrap
{
    static IWindsorContainer container;
    public static IWindsorContainer Container { get { return container; } }
    public static void Boot()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Install(new 
   ApiLog.Installer(connectionstring));


    }
}

 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
         .......
         bootstrap.Boot();
        ...
        //warm up BusinessContext
       var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)BusinessContext.GetCurrDBContext()).ObjectContext;
        var mappingCollection = (StorageMappingItemCollection)objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSSpace);


    }
}
```

the api runs well normally. but if i continuously hit f5 continuous( 7-13 times) after a fresh build,  various exceptions throw（4 types of exception so far):

```
  Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions.

Source Error: 

Line 45:         {Line 46:             db.LogBases.Add(log);Line 47:             db.SaveChanges();Line 48:         }Line 49:         public ApiLogBase GetOne(int id)

Source File: C:\Dev\code\ls_server\zjwist.log\ZJWistLog\LogRepository.cs    Line: 47 




Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Source Error: 

Line 45:         {Line 46:             db.LogBases.Add(log);Line 47:             db.SaveChanges();Line 48:         }Line 49:         public ApiLogBase GetOne(int id)


Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Source Error: 

Line 44:         public void AddLog(ApiLogBase log)Line 45:         {Line 46:             db.LogBases.Add(log);Line 47:             db.SaveChanges();Line 48:         }

Source File: C:\Dev\code\ls_server\zjwist.log\ZJWistLog\LogRepository.cs    Line: 46 


Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.

Source Error: 

Line 45:         {Line 46:             db.LogBases.Add(log);Line 47:             db.SaveChanges();Line 48:         }Line 49:         public ApiLogBase GetOne(int id)

Source File: C:\Dev\code\ls_server\zjwist.log\ZJWistLog\LogRepository.cs    Line: 47
```

any sugguestion will be preciated.

Comment: This is not really an EF question.  Somehow you are using DbContext instances concurrently from different threads, which is not supported.  The fault lies somewhere in your repository or dependency injection setup.

Comment: What happens inside `BusinessContext.GetCurrDBContext()`?

Comment: @Gert i have updated the question

Comment: @David yes ,the exceptions show that it is a multithreading vs dbcontext problem. but why ef doesnt handle this,or how to hand this. it is a common need for sysytem intergration .

Comment: As I thought, you have one cached context instance that's used everywhere. That's a major anti pattern.Use one context per request. Contexts aren't thread-safe and there's no compelling reason why they should be.

Comment: @Gert "cached context " means  DbContext,not CallContext,yes?  "use one context per request" means new BusinessContexts ()  and  new LogContext() on every httprequest?   like creat a new ISession in Nhibernate?

Comment: You can choose between using a new DbContext for each Http request, and using a new, localDbContext for each method that needs one.

Comment: i think i found where the problem is. it is in the constructor of LogRepository. the contructor will be excuted just once in the application lifetime, becauce singleton is the default lifestyle of Castle.Windsor, so the logContext has no chance to be renewd in every request, it will always be the first one when application start( iis website/apppool start).  i think this is  Gert Arnold  said "one cached context".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found where the problem is. it is in the constructor of LogRepository. the contructor will be excuted just once during the application lifetime, because singleton is the default lifestyle of Castle.Windsor, so the logContext has no chance to be renewd in afterward requests, it will always be  the first one when application started( iis website/apppool start)， as  Gert Arnold  said,the  "one cached context".